# iTextSharp - very large table memory leak

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I have a `SqlDataReader` reading a large record set (1M records approx.) and I'm trying to export it to a PDF document using iTextSharp.
This is my code:

```
 if (reader.HasRows)
 {
    int rowNum = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
       if (rowNum % 2 == 1)
          datatable.DefaultCell.GrayFill = 0.8f;
       else
          datatable.DefaultCell.GrayFill = 0.95f;
       if (meRes.Trans(Lang, "Dir", CompanyID).ToUpper() == "RTL")
          for (int i = reader.FieldCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
          {
             object o = reader[i];
             datatable.AddCell(new Phrase(o.ToString(), fntList));
          }
       else
          for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
             {
                object o = reader[i];
                datatable.AddCell(new Phrase(o.ToString(), fntList));
             }
       rowNum++;
   }
    myDocument.Add(datatable);
 }
```

When I run this, it causing a terrible memory leak.
What can I do differently to improve this?

Comment: You create an object for every loop in your conditions like `object o = reader[i];`.  That could be the problem

Comment: I don't think this is the problem because if I'm doing `datatable.AddCell(new Phrase(reader[i], fntList));` It still cause the memory leak

Comment: All during your loop you export data into datatable which is an in-memory representation of the data. Until your mydocument.Add(datatable) everything accumulates in memory. There is no leak, merely a bad design.

Comment: thanks @mkl, what you suggest I should do instead in order to improve that?

Comment: @VahidN meanwhile suggested a way. More details may be available from iText in Action, 2nd edition, and the samples which are available online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the number of rows per page to reduce the memory pressure

```
if (rowNum>0 && table1.Rows.Count % 7 == 0) // 7 = number of rows per page
{
   pdfDoc.Add(table1);
   table1.DeleteBodyRows(); // free resources
   pdfDoc.NewPage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it sounds good, but is there a way to know how many space is left in the same page after we add the table in order to prevent large blank spaces?

Comment: After pdfDoc.Add(table1), you will have access to the table's height value. reduce it from the page size and margins to calculate the height of the empty space.