# iTextSharp large table: adding in chunks leaves visible gaps in the table

Tags: itext

I have a large table I'm adding to a document. In order to avoid running out of memory, I'm doing this:

```
if (rowCounter % 100 == 0)
{
   document.Add(affidavitsTable);
}
```

That improved performance, but now, after ever 100 rows, there's a gap in the middle of the table:

I've placed a screenshot [**here**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzEXwvdSgR-gb0t3aVJMSlhhUlE/view?usp=sharing) - sorry can't post images yet... :-/

I'm don't really understand what the comments mean [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14109082/2292732) but I'm wondering if it's related.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Eliezer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. This line was hiding in my code:

```
affidavitsTable.SpacingBefore = 8;
```

:-\